# how to perform long running operation using foreground services in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, background, foreground-service

When I used foreground service then when I kill the application then foreground service is automatically killed but I want to alive foreground service when the application is killed. this issue appeared in android 10 and android 11. how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as you should not be able to keep alive a foreground service after the application is killed.

> You should only use a foreground service when your app needs to perform a task that is noticeable by the user even when they're not directly interacting with the app. If the action is of low enough importance that you want to use a minimum-priority notification, create a background task instead.

If you what to have some background service working, that will be possible.
You can find some useful information here :

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services
2. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Answer (score 0):

It should not get killed. When starting foreground service you need to create notification too. You have done that, right?

If you done everything right there is possibility that you have xiaomi phone. Xiaomi deletes everything when app killed. You need to add specific intent protection...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).